# What the function rpcToken = Math.round(1E8 * Double.parseDouble("0." + (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE))); do in java?

Tags: java

Hello I an not a java programmer,

I need know what this function does:

```
rpcToken = Math.round(1E8 * Double.parseDouble("0." + (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
```

This just generate a random 8 number string? I need to make this exactly in PHP.

Thank you

Comment: That code is awful. It should just be generating the number directly, and not converting to a string and back.

Comment: `Math.round(1E8 * Math.random())` would be more like it.

Comment: No, that wouldn't quite do the same thing as this code.

Comment: It seems to be an extremely bad way to generate a random number between `0` and `100000000` (inclusive), with a less-than-random distribution curve. It does not generate a string. A better way would have been to call [`nextInt(100000001)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) on a `Random` object, or [what @4castle said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401511/what-the-function-rpctoken-math-round1e8-double-parsedouble0-int-m#comment73863805_43401511).

Comment: "I need know what this function does" - Hire a programmer, or get help from your friends or colleagues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.random()` gives you a pseudorandom number less than 1 but at least 0.

This is multiplied by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is 2147483647.  The result is a number between 0 and 2147483646.

`(int)` converts this number to an integer.

`"0." +` converts this to a `String`, and adds "0." to the beginning of it.

`Double.parseDouble` converts this `String` back to a `double`.  So now we again have a number between 0 and 1.  But any number greater than 0 but less than 0.1 is impossible due to the way we created the String.  "0.9" and "0.900" would both convert to 0.9.

`1E8 *` multiplies this by 1E8, which is 100000000.

And finally, `Math.round` rounds this off to the nearest integer.

So, in total, we have a supposedly random number somewhere between 0 and 99999999, but the final result is very skewed.  Many numbers are impossible to generate with this code (numbers between 1 and 9999999 seem impossible, but 0 is still possible) and this code will generate certain numbers more often than other numbers (close to half the generated numbers will begin with 1, and more than average may end with 0), and I find it very unlikely that all of this is intentional (although it's impossible to say for sure without knowing the code's purpose.)

If you just need a random 8 digit number, there are easier, faster, and better ways.  Why not just multiply that random number you got in the first step by 100000000, and round it off?

Comment: In fact I found this code in one function from a class that I want to make a similar one, but in PHP, so how I don't know java I need to understand exactly what this make to replicate this in PHP. Your answer was very complete and helpful. Thank you!